MOSFETs longevity & efficiency: On-state + act of turning on VS body diode. Which state impacts lifetime/longevity more? Which is more efficient?
So if you have a back to back MOSFET pair (drain touching drain or source touching source) in series, and you want to conduct current in one direction. You have two options starting from a state where both are off:
(a) turn on both MOSFETs and conduct the current [with turning off after finishing with the operation], or
(b) turn on one MOSFET and leave the other (2nd) MOSFET off so the body diode flows in the desired direction.
Besides (b) having the benefit that current should generally flow in only the one desired direction, I would like to inquire on the benefits of state (b) vs state (a):
(1) Would using the body diode of the one MOSFET be as efficient as having both MOSFETs on, or is one generally more efficient than the other?
(2) Would the act of switching on/activating the 2nd MOSFET to allow current to flow through that MOSFET and having to later turn that 2nd MOSFET off reduce the longevity/durability rather than just using the body diode of the 2nd MOSFET and leaving it off?
Even miniscule differences are important to me, so I would appreciate your help.
